# PIL cannot write mode F to jpeg

Tags: jpeg, python-imaging-library, fft, mode, ioerror

I am taking a jpg image and using numpy's fft2 to create/save a new image. However it throws this error

```
"IOError: cannot write mode F as JPEG"
```

Is there an issue with CMYK and JPEG files in PIL???

```
p = Image.open('kibera.jpg')
bw_p = p.convert('L')
array_p = numpy.asarray(bw_p)
fft_p = abs(numpy.fft.rfft2(array_p))
new_p = Image.fromarray(fft_p)
new_p.save('kibera0.jpg')
new_p.histogram()
```

Answer (score 81):

Try convert the image to RGB:

```
...
new_p = Image.fromarray(fft_p)
if new_p.mode != 'RGB':
    new_p = new_p.convert('RGB')
...
```

Comment: What if an image is in grayscale?

Comment: Bump, what if I want to save as grayscale?

Comment: Just use this. It works just fine with grayscale as well.

Answer (score 52):

[Semente's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18879396) is right for color images
For grayscale images you can use below:-

```
new_p = Image.fromarray(fft_p)
new_p = new_p.convert("L")
```

If you use `new_p = new_p.convert('RGB')` for a grayscale image then the image will still have 24 bit depth instead of 8 bit and would occupy thrice the size on hard disk and it wont be a true grayscale image.

Comment: More info on convert here: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert

Answer (score 21):

I think it may be that your `fft_p` array is in float type and the image should have every pixel in the format 0-255 (which is uint8), so maybe you can try doing this before creating the image from array:

```py
fft_p = fft_p.astype(np.uint8)
new_p = Image.fromarray(fft_p)
```

But be aware that every element in the `fft_p` array should be in the 0-255 range, so maybe you would need to do some processing to that before to get the desired results, for example if you every element is a float between 0 and 1 you can multiply them by 255.

Comment: This is the true answer because it does not changing the actual value of the numpy array (just the type format).

Comment: Very useful hint that it should be `uint8`. I was trying to preview the mnist grayscale data on jupyter and encountered this issue. The correct code should be like `Image.fromarray((mnist_images[0]*255).astype(np.uint8))

Answer (score 3):

```py
def save_img(img, path):

    img = Image.fromarray(img)

    img.save(path)

raise OSError(f"cannot write mode {mode} as PNG") from e
```

> OSError: cannot write mode F as PNG

Here the meaning of mode `F` is the floating point value in the image. So please convert the floating point image to the `uint8` image before saving.

```
image.astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are working with PyTorch**

```
import torchvision.transforms as T
    
        
transform=T.ToPILImage()
imt=transform(img)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but my image was a gray-scale one, consisting of only float numbers between 0 and 1.
I was able to save my image with the original data through the following method:

```
import PIL as pillow, numpy

# Normalize the image with values between 0 and 255
normalized_image = (final_image - numpy.min(final_image)) * (255.0 / (numpy.max(final_image) - numpy.min(final_image)))
normalized_image = normalized_image.astype('uint8')

# Convert the normalized numpy array to an image using Pillow
image = pillow.Image.fromarray(normalized_image)

# Save the final image
image.save('image.png')
```